# WindowsBuilder was not able to show GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowsbuilder, windows-build-tools

I am using `Eclipse 2021-06` latest version. I was using `windowsbuilder` and suddenly it started to show me this error saying:

`WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error.This could be caused by a WindowBuilder bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partialupdate, etc.`

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.Property$1 cannot be cast to class java.awt.Font (org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.Property$1 is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6980fa39; java.awt.Font is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')`

I tried tracing the stack and got this list of errors I guess:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.Property$1 cannot be cast to class java.awt.Font (org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.Property$1 is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6980fa39; java.awt.Font is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.property.editor.font.DerivedFontPage.configure(DerivedFontPage.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.property.editor.font.FontPropertyEditor.openDialog(FontPropertyEditor.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.editor.TextDialogPropertyEditor$1.onClick(TextDialogPropertyEditor.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.editor.presentation.ButtonPropertyEditorPresentationImpl$4.handleEvent(ButtonPropertyEditorPresentationImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1435)


Full context stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.Property$1 cannot be cast to class java.awt.Font (org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.Property$1 is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6980fa39; java.awt.Font is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.property.editor.font.DerivedFontPage.configure(DerivedFontPage.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.property.editor.font.FontPropertyEditor.openDialog(FontPropertyEditor.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.editor.TextDialogPropertyEditor$1.onClick(TextDialogPropertyEditor.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.editor.presentation.ButtonPropertyEditorPresentationImpl$4.handleEvent(ButtonPropertyEditorPresentationImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1435)
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Please show your `eclipse.ini` file (next to the `eclipse` executable file). Please show the error log starting with `!SESSION`.

Comment: In case you updated Eclipse to 2021-06 and use the included Java without updating WindowBuilder, you will face [this already fixed issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572210). If you already use the latest WindowBuilder (please tell the version you have), please provide the information I asked you in my first comment.